# What is the relationship between outer transaction and inner transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, propagation

I am new to Hibernate and when I am using transactions I met couple of questions. Previously, the situation is

```
@Transactional
Class A {
  methodA1(){
    DOs = fetchDOsFromDB();
    methodA2(DOs);
  }
    methodA2(DOs){
    ClassB.methodB1(DOs);
  }
}

Class B{
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  methodB1(DOs){
    dealWithDOs();
  }
}
```

But I found when the amount of DOs is huge, it will give connection is closed exception. So I am wondering if the root cause is I passed the DOs to methodB1 which bound with transaction in A and the transaction A can't be committed for a long time.

So this is the first question, I know `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` will make the outer transaction be suspended but what does suspend exactly mean? Does it have timeout?

And if I don't pass `DOs` to `classB`, instead, I do

```
methodA1(){
DOs = fetchDOsFromDB();
List<Integer> list = getIds(DOs);
methodA2(list);
}

methodA2(list){
 ClassB.methodB1(list);
}
```

which means I am not relying on `DOs`, will this help?

Is there any relationship between the commit of transaction A and the running result of transaction B? In other words, does the commit of transaction A need to wait for the completion of `methodB1`?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` you are telling the persistence provider to start what is called a **nested transaction**. Oracle documentation has some good explanation of this topic:

1. What does suspend exactly mean?

   > While the nested (child) transaction is active, the parent transaction
   >   may not perform any operations other than to commit or abort, or to
   >   create more child transactions.
2. Is there any relationship between the commitment of transaction A and the running result of transaction B?

   > Committing a nested transaction has no effect on the state of the
   >   parent transaction. The parent transaction is still uncommitted.
   >   However, the parent transaction can now see any modifications made by
   >   the child transaction. Those modifications, of course, are still
   >   hidden to all other transactions until the parent also commits.
3. In other words, does the commitment of transaction A need to wait for the completion of methodB1?

   > If the parent transaction commits or aborts while it has active
   >   children, the child transactions are resolved in the same way as the
   >   parent. That is, if the parent aborts, then the child transactions
   >   abort as well. If the parent commits, then whatever modifications have
   >   been performed by the child transactions are also committed.

So, no A does not need to wait for B to commit, which can actually rollback and A can still commit.